# Converting character variable into date variable with only years in R

Tags: r, date

I have a character variable with n observations per year, like this:

```
Years <- c("2010","2010","2011", "2011", "2012", "2012")
```

I would like R to read these characters as actual years, therefore I tried with

```
dates <- as.Date(Years, format = "%Y")
```

But the output obtained is this:

```
[1] "2010-09-24" "2010-09-24" "2011-09-24" "2011-09-24" "2012-09-24" "2012-09-24"
```

while I would like to keep them only with the year.

Is it possible to obtain a Date variable with only the years?

Thanks

Comment: R's `Date` class is not a `Year` class, so it must be a *specific day/date*. Which day of the year do you want to use? If you don't want a particular day, is there a reason the numeric or integer `2010` is insufficient?

Comment: I would like to use this variable as index to create a timeseries with xts.

Comment: `as.numeric` (or perhaps `as.integer`) should work fine for that.

Comment: I actually just tried with the numeric version with

   ts <- xts(x = df, order.by = years)

But i receive the error: order.by requires an appropriate time-based object

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. If you need a `Date`, then you need a date. I suggest either using the current day or choosing a specific day of the year, perhaps `as.Date(paste0(Years, "-01-01"))`. Does that work for you?

Comment: in your call to `xts(.)`, was `years` a `character` or `numeric` vector?

Comment: A Character... I tried with  as.Date(paste0(Years, "-01-01")), but the variable becomes numeric

Comment: yeah, the "time" in time series isn't categorical, so it makes sense to convert that to a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date class objects require a year, month and day.  If you only have a year then you either have to add a month and day or not use Date class.

Also a time series should have one point for each index value.  Aggregate the values corresonding to each year using `mean`, `tail1 <- function(x) tail(x, 1)` or other aggregation function so that there is only one point per year.

xts does not support just a year as the index but zoo does and if the series is regularly spaced a ts series could be used as well.

```
library(zoo)

# note that we are assuming a numeric year
DF <- data.frame(year = c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012), value = 1:5)
z <- read.zoo(DF, aggregate = mean)
tt <- as.ts(z)
```

Another possibility is to use yearmon or yearqtr class.  This has both a year and month or a year and a quarter but you don't need a day and internally January or Q1 is stored as a number equal to the year.

```
library(xts)

zm <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = mean)
xm <- as.xts(zm)

zq <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = as.yearqtr, aggregate = mean)
xq <- as.xts(zq)
```